# Can I see my rejected edits?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718974/verify-existence-of-non-public-property-by-name-in-xamarin-pcl), the answer from Furkan Fidan did not quite fit my problem, because he overread the "PCL" part. However in the comments he gave the right tip, and to credit him I asked him to edit his answer and then I'd accept it. He edited, but not in the way I intended to (I wanted the wrong code to be replaced, not kept with a note that it's the wrong code).

So I edited the answer myself and then accepted it - or so I thought.

*Now* I see the answer is accepted but the wrong code is still there. I remember I typed the correct code, and I thought I had saved he edit and it said "The edit will only be visible to you until it's peer reviewed". I'm also quite certain I'd always edit first and only then accept second, so at no time there's an accepted answer with the incorrect code and no hint that it was incorrect.

Now the correct code is not there, and I wonder: Was the edit rejected and I can't see my rejected edits? Did something go wrong when I edited the post? Was the peer review note I remember getting issued for a different edit?

So my question: can someone with enough reputation please have a look if the edit was rejected? With SO, I never know how much is hidden from me because of low reputation. That left me not even trusting SO to display all my own edits to me.

Comment: You don't even need an account to see every edit suggested by every user.  It's all public, even for users that aren't logged in.

Comment: Thanks, but the support call you linked to is from 2014. Support calls cannot be a duplicate of a non-recent ticket, because how could I tell whether the answer still applies or whether it has changed in the last 2.5 years?

Comment: There is no such restriction on what posts can be closed as duplicates.  If you actually read the answer, you'll be able to see for yourself if it has in fact changed in the past few years.

Comment: I've already been to my activity tab, but there is no "suggestions".

Comment: I just used it to look at the edit you suggested that was rejected.  I can assure you that it's there.

Comment: Now with NathanOliver's answer I found the place that other answer refers to. The answer there states "go to the activity tab, and filter on suggestions", but the actual way is "go to the activity tab, **click on all actions** and then filter on suggestions." Can you edit that answer to contain all steps to see the suggestions?

Comment: You're more than welcome to edit it yourself, if you would like to.

Comment: I had if I could, but it says "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta-sites.". I assume you can only edit if you have enough reputation so your edit will not be a suggested edit but instantly accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see all your edit suggestions and the status of them by going to your profile, click on the activity page, click on all actions (kind in the middle of the page vertically), then click on suggestions.  For you that gives you [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1843468/lwchris?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and for [anyone else use go to this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: So what you're saying is "if you don't see the edit, you didn't make it" - hence I didn't make that edit? Weird.

Comment: @LWChris Yep.  If the edit is not there then it never happened.

Comment: Ah NOW I found the edit with the link. Still don't see how to get there from the UI, my activitity tab has no "Suggestions".

Comment: @LWChris Are you on the all actions tab?

Comment: Hah found it. The "all actions" was the missing link. You wrote it, but the original answer I was referred to said "go to the activity tab, and filter on suggestions" which is impossible. Thank you.